# Json Data Passing into Dropdownlist Selected Angular

Tags: angular

i am creating simple crud application using Angular.i want to edit the record when i click edit button on the table row editing row are passing to textbox field successfully but dropdownlist is true or set i set it.if the json data come as true True need to be selected if the false False need to be selected.what i tried so far i attached below. can you help me how to selected as dropdown list.

```
               <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <mat-label>Complete</mat-label>
                    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="complete"  name="complete" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"   >
                      <mat-option   value="true">True</mat-option>
                      <mat-option value="false">False</mat-option>

                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
```

**here is ts file**

```
setUpdate(data:any)
{

     this.taskname = data.taskname;
     this.description = data.description;
     this.complete = data.complete;
 
}
```

**here is edit button**

```
 <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="setUpdate(row)">
                            <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" fontIcon="edit"></mat-icon>
                          </button>
                          &nbsp;
```

**Screen Shot**
[image]

Comment: There are no "edit button" place holder in your sample code, please complete the sameple code.

Comment: can you now i correct it

Comment: No, what is this `selectData(complete)`.

Comment: sorry sir that code is wrong

Comment: lets remove the code selectData(complete)

Comment: did you check my code

Comment: if the json data come as true, provide the json data as well? please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256328/discussion-between-paypal-kob-and-akizukilenn).

Comment: {taskid: 1, taskname: 't', description: 'tas', complete: false, employee: {…}}
1
: 
{taskid: 3, taskname: 'asd', description: 'asd', complete: false, employee: {…}}
2
: 
{taskid: 4, taskname: 'C', description: 'df', complete: true, employee: {…}}
3
: 
{taskid: 7, taskname: 'sdas', description: 'asdas', complete: true, employee: {…}}
4
: 
{taskid: 19, taskname: 'sad', description: 'asd', complete: true, employee: {…}}
5
: 
{taskid: 22, taskname: 'qwe', description: 'dfdfsdf', complete: true, employee: {…}}
length
: 
6

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding so far.
You have rows. These rows are object from a JSON (by using `JSON.parse` you can parse JSON into an object).
When user click on an edit button from the row. The data from the row is read and inside the option, the "complete" field should be either true or false according to that row.

The code you provided so far should perform exactly what you expected had you implement correctly. If you can print any console error it would be great help to clarify the answer.

Try checking whatever is passing into the `setUpdate(row)` function.